# iOS not using -568h@2x.png

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have 3 images:

```
test.png
test@2x.png
test-568@2x.png
```

In IBOutlet, a UIImageView is set to display test.png.

On iPhone 3.5in without retina, it's displaying test.png

On iPhone 3.5in with retina, it's displaying test@2x.png

But on iPhone 4in with retina, it's displaying test@2x.png!!!

What's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-568@2x` suffix only applies to the Default.png launch images. There is no special suffix used by `UIImage imageNamed:` (or the other `UIImage` methods). If you need a special image on the 4" screen, you need to add code to get the desired image yourself.

Comment: Do you really have full screen sized images besides the launch image? That's the only reason to need different images for the different screen sizes, at least that I can think of. It's trivial to write a couple extra lines of code for the rare case this is an issue.

Comment: @rmaddy - Full-screen background images are an example of why you need this. So now, through code, we have to do a hack and check the aspect ratio of the display and programmatically swap out the correct image...

Comment: What? A spent several hours now by this problem. I really don't understand this.

Answer (score 7):

The following works for the iPhone. For the iPad, you would need additional images.

For the three versions of the background image, use the following names:

1. background-480h.png (320x480)
2. background-480h@2x.png (640x960)
3. background-568h@2x.png (640x1136)

(You don't need a "-568h.png" image because there's no 320x568 iPhone screen.)

When you set the background image, simply append the screen height to the image name:

```
NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"background-%ih", (int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height];
[view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]]];
```

iOS automtically appends the "@2x" if applicable.

You could omit the "h" after the height in the image names, but I think it's nice to emulate the iOS convention for the default image.

Comment: Thanks!!!  This is a MUCH more elegant and simple solution than other answers I've seen to this question.  Most other people are recommending overriding the UIImage methods (such [this approach](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/20-iPhone5-568h-image-loading)), but that seems like overkill to me

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old thread but I was having trouble with the new screen sizes for iPhone 6/6+.

What I did is to use this naming convention for different image files:

- **none** if @1x small old phones
- **@2x** for iPhone 4
- **-568h@2x** for iPhone 5
- **-667h@2x** for iPhone 6
- **@3x** for iPhone 6 Plus

And then to automatically generate (full size) images just by including the code from this Gist in the project:
https://gist.github.com/kevindelord/fe2e691d06ab745fbb00

You have nothing else to do. When you instantiate an image in your code:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png”];
```

The categorised class from the Gist will `automatically` create an image corresponding to the current device.

There is a Pod for it [UIImage+Autoresize](https://github.com/kevindelord/UIImage-Autoresize) documented on [CocoaDocs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/UIImage+Autoresize).

Comment: What is the purpose of DKHelper extension?

Comment: The DKHelper is library containing a bunch of categorised classes to improve the everyday iOS development. There are nice methods to deal with NSDates, NSPredicates and so on. I will be glad if you use it!

Comment: What is the purpose of DKHelper extension in this context?

Comment: The DKHelper includes this categorised class. You could integrate it and enjoy some of the classes or just the gist included by yourself in the code.

Comment: My point is that iOS by DEFAULT does what this category does. So what is the purpose of this category?

Comment: Well I'm sorry but I search all over the Internet and tried everything by myself and it didn't work. So far as I saw/know Apple didn't create this logic. But if you know the default valid solution I would gladly know it! Here is the project I developed this code with: https://github.com/kevindelord/DKScreenSize
Feel free to take a look and tell me what's wrong

Comment: This logic with @2x exists I agree on that. but I didn't find anything when it comes to deal with full size -667h images, and before iOS8/iPhone6 I also had to manually deal with -568h pictures.