# Adjust background image size of SpriteKit ios app

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a working SpriteKit app for my iphone 5; however, when I run the same app on my iphone 4* the background image gets clipped and my obstacle height calculations break.  I have tried different scaleModes as well as adding a background.png and background@2x.png, but the smaller res picture is not working.  I can determine the size of the display and explicitly pick the right image file, but this does not seam as elegant as I would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I believe that in your case you do have to check the size of the display. As inelegant as it may be.

Check this answer out:
[iOS not using -568h@2x.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170306/ios-not-using-568h2x-png)

Comment: i dont get it - my original project only had background@2x.png and it found it.  This is just a gap, for all the ridiculous number of launch and icon images required for today's app, you would think this sort of sugar would be a given.  totally weak!